# EBS snapshots: exporting only delta

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, export, amazon-ebs

Can I somehow export to S3 only EBS snapshot's delta (i.e changes from previous snapshot)?

I'm trying to export EC2 instance to S3 and exporting everytime AMI/full instance volumes looks expensive for me.

Anyway if I don't want to export using AMI way, I have to take EBS snapshot from instance volume and than

1. make temporary volume from it
2. attach temporary volume to other instance/agent and than copy contents to S3 bucket

And what I want - to avoid 1 step - i.e somehow directly get blocks changes according to internal EBS snapshot structure and push them to S3.

I heard, that EBS snapshots have already stored in S3 (but in invisible regions) - Amazon really doesn't provide any public API to 1to1 copying to user's regions or make them visible without restoring full history from first full snapshot?

Comment: It's not clear what you are *actually* trying to accomplish, or what your motivation is, though it appears to be cost-related.  EBS already stores your volume snapshots deduplicated, and you only pay for the actual storage necessary to store the unique blocks required to restore all of the snapshots you have retained.  Blocks that are no longer needed because the last snapshot that depended on them has been deleted are no longer retained.  Why are you trying to store these, separately, in S3?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i need to export instances into S3 to reuse them later locally - and export huge AMI's or full volume images is expensive for me. But question is more about aws api, can use help me with that - am i clearly undestand that there is no public amazon api to retrieve only single snapshot contents?